# Lightest serialization method for simple data structure

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm having a simple data structure which I want to serialize without adding too much overhead.
Which approach you consider the best in terms of data size?

- Custom serialization/deserialization using separators as "#" or other character I am 100% is not present in my data
- XmlSerialization
- JSON
- Other

I'm using custom serialization with # as separator because I'm 100% sure I don't have that character in my data.

Data structure example:

```
string        Title       
int           ChapterIndex
List<String>  Paragraphs
```

I have a list of the object above

1. No optimization (tabs and spaces)

**JSON:**

```
[
 {
    "title": "some title 0",
    "chapterIndex": 0,
    "paragraphs": ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"]
 },
 {
    "title": "some title 1",
    "chapterIndex": 1,
    "paragraphs": ["p1chap1", "p2chap1", "p3chap1", "p4chap1"]
 }
]
```

**XML:**

```
<RootTag>
    <item title="some title 0" chapterIndex="0">
        <paragraph>p1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>p2</paragraph>
        <paragraph>p3</paragraph>
        <paragraph>p4</paragraph>
    </item>
    <item title="some title 1" chapterIndex="1">
        <paragraph>p1chap1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>p2chap1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>p3chap1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>p4chap1</paragraph>
    </item>
</RootTag>
```

2. Optimized (no unnecessary characters)

**JSON:**

```
[{"title":"some title 0","chapterIndex":0,"paragraphs":["p1","p2","p3","p4"]},{"title":"some title 1","chapterIndex":1,"paragraphs":["p1chap1","p2chap1","p3chap1","p4chap1"]}]
```

**XML:**

```
<RootTag><item title="some title 0" chapterIndex="0"><paragraph>p1</paragraph><paragraph>p2</paragraph><paragraph>p3</paragraph><paragraph>p4</paragraph></item><item title="some title 1" chapterIndex="1"><paragraph>p1chap1</paragraph><paragraph>p2chap1</paragraph><paragraph>p3chap1</paragraph><paragraph>p4chap1</paragraph></item></RootTag>
```

**Custom:**

```
some title 0##0##p1#p2#p3#p4###some title 1##1##p1chap1#p2chap1#p3chap1#p4chap1###and_so_on
```

**Custom optimized:**

```
some title 0§0§p1#p2#p3#p4¤some title 1§1§p1chap1#p2chap1#p3chap1#p4chap1¤and_so_on
```

having

- ¤ as list item separator
- § as properties inside item separator
- # as paragraph content separator

**UPDATE:** 
In my case I have strings more than integers since it's kind of a book/lyrics application which only needs title chapternumber/lyricId and all the paragraphs of the lyrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying all serialization types provided in answers I've come to an answer to my question.

When and **only** when the requirements are these:

- **Data size priority**
- **Simple data structure**
- **Custom Serialization and Deserialization required**
- **Know the content of your data to choose your separators properly**

only under these conditions is a win to use a Custom serialization as shown in my  question.

About performance?
It all depends on how you write your de/serialization methods.

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable conclusion. Congrats to really *thinking* about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is complex to decide. If your classes are composed primarily of strings, then your approach is the better one. The only "more better" approach would be to compress the resulting stream (something that you can still do after creating the serialized data).

If your data is primarily numeric/non-string, then [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)/[protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) are binary serializers, and their output should be smaller than your serializer, because you use 5 bytes to serialize `10000`, while a binary serializer will probably use only 2-4 bytes.

Json and xml serializer will surely produce bigger serialized data, because they are both "textual" (so they serialize the number `10000` as `10000`) (as is your serializer) *and* they include additional markup that, being non-empty, is by definition non-smaller than a single character.

Now... is it better to write a custom serializer or to use [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)? I'll say that I would trust more a serializer written by Marc Gravell (protobuf) and based on a "standard" created by google than a serializer written by me :-) As it is now you are serializing integer numbers and strings... But perhaps tomorrow you'll need to serialize `DateTime` or `float` or other complex types. Are 100 less bytes better than the hours you'll need to use to implement correctly the serialization? It is you that have to decide it.

An example with Protobuf:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int chapterIndex { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public List<String> paragraphs { get; set; }
}

var myo = new[] 
{ 
    new MyObject
    {
        title = "some title 0",
        chapterIndex = 0,
        paragraphs = new List<string> { "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4" }
    }, 
    new MyObject
    {
        title = "some title 1",
        chapterIndex = 1,
        paragraphs = new List<string> { "p1chap1", "p2chap1", "p3chap1", "p4chap1" }
    }, 
};

byte[] bytes;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(ms, myo);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    MyObject[] myo2 = Serializer.Deserialize<MyObject[]>(ms);
}
```

The length of the `byte[]` is 86, so just a little longer than your custom formatter (81). But note that this is with a single numeric field, and you used single digit numbers. The point is that `protobuf` is still probably better, because it has been written by a professional, and doesn't have limitations as your serializer.

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, Is there a hybrid way to serialize let's say numbers to char to avoid using 4 bytes for a 2 byte number considering my data is mostly string? Can you  provide example of serialization result in protobuf based on my data?

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml Done the second part. For the first part, I won't help you waste hours to save some bytes

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion JSON is the simplest method and also generates no overhead.
Here: http://json.org/example you can see the difference between JSON and XML.

And the JSON Parser will do everything automatically for you.

Comment: I'm not sure about no overhead  there is always overhead/extra data to separate items

Comment: In my opinion it isn't overhead. For me, overhead is what XML do. EDIT: But I think that your method is way shorter and looks pretty good.

Comment: You're right i was misunderstanding overhead word, interpreting it as extra/accessory

Comment: No problem. Well, I think you answered your own question. You should use your method. Or do you have any other question about this topic?

Comment: I'm waiting that people who answered proto-buf provide an example to see if that is better/lighter than custom example

Answer (score 0):

I've been using google's [proto-buf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) serialization in my project and it's one of the lightest so far.